# How can I hide fields "from" and "to" if I choose "no" in the select field?

Tags: magento2.2, admin-panel, custom-field

I have three custom attributes in the edit product page.

[image]

I need hide fields "From" and "To" if choose value "No" in the select and vice versa.
How can I do it?
Thanks you.

How I did that:

1. Created the attributes:
   **app/code/Ns/My_module/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php**:

   ```
    <?php
    namespace NS\My_module\Setup;

    use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

    class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface {
        protected $customerSetupFactory;
        private $attributeSetFactory;

        const IS_PRESALE = 'is_presale_product';
        const PRESALE_START = 'presale_product_from';
        const PRESALE_FINISH = 'presale_product_to';

        public function __construct(
            CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
            AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
        ) {
            $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
            $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        }

        public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $setup->startSetup();
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
            if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {

                $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                    self::IS_PRESALE,
                    [
                        'group' => "",
                        'label' => "Is PreSale?",
                        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                        'default' => '1',
                        'note' => '',
                        'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'visible' => true,
                        'required' => false,
                        'user_defined' => false,
                        'searchable' => false,
                        'filterable' => false,
                        'comparable' => false,
                        'visible_on_front' => true,
                        'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
                        'unique' => false,
                        "frontend_class" => "",
                        "used_in_product_listing" => true,
                        "input" => "select",
                        "type" => "varchar",
                        "source" => "NS\My_module\Model\Config\Source\PresaleSchedule",
                        'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend'
                    ]
                );

                $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                    self::PRESALE_START,
                    [
                        'group' => '',
                        'label' => 'Presale From',
                        'type' => 'datetime',
                        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                        'default' => '',
                        'note' => '',
                        'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'visible' => true,
                        'required' => false,
                        'user_defined' => false,
                        'searchable' => false,
                        'filterable' => false,
                        'comparable' => false,
                        'visible_on_front' => true,
                        'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
                        'unique' => false,
                        'frontend_class' => '',
                        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                        'input' => 'date',
                        'source' => '',
                        'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                    ]
                );

                $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                    self::PRESALE_FINISH,
                    [
                        'group' => '',
                        'label' => 'Presale To',
                        'type' => 'datetime',
                        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                        'default' => '',
                        'note' => '',
                        'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'visible' => true,
                        'required' => false,
                        'user_defined' => false,
                        'searchable' => false,
                        'filterable' => false,
                        'comparable' => false,
                        'visible_on_front' => true,
                        'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
                        'unique' => false,
                        'frontend_class' => '',
                        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                        'input' => 'date',
                        'source' => '',
                        'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                    ]
                );
            }

            $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
   ```
2. Created the **app/code/NS/My_module/Model/Config/Source/PresaleSchedule.php**:

   ```
    <?php
    namespace NS\My_module\Model\Config\Source;

    class PresaleSchedule extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource {

        protected $_optionsData;

        public function getAllOptions()
        {
            if ($this->_options === null) {
                $this->_options = [
                    ['value' => '0', 'label' => __('No')],
                    ['value' => '1', 'label' => __('Yes')]
                ];
            }
            return $this->_options;
        }
    }
   ```

   }
3. Created the **app/code/NS/My_module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/PreSellDesignUpdate.php**:

   ```
    <?php
    namespace NS\My_module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

    use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
    use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;

    class PreSellDesignUpdate extends AbstractModifier {

        const PRESALE_START = 'presale_product_from';
        const PRESALE_END = 'presale_product_to';
        protected $arrayManager;

            public function __construct(ArrayManager $arrayManager)
            {
                $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
            }

            public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
            {
                return $this->customizeDateRangeField($meta);
            }

            public function modifyData(array $data)
            {
                return $data;
            }

            protected function customizeDateRangeField(array $meta)
            {
                if ($this->getGroupCodeByField($meta, self::PRESALE_START)
                    !== $this->getGroupCodeByField($meta, self::PRESALE_END)
                ) {
                    return $meta;
                }

                $fromFieldPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath(self::PRESALE_START, $meta, null, 'children');
                $toFieldPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath(self::PRESALE_END, $meta, null, 'children');
                $fromContainerPath = $this->arrayManager->slicePath($fromFieldPath, 0, -2);
                $toContainerPath = $this->arrayManager->slicePath($toFieldPath, 0, -2);

                $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
                    $fromFieldPath . self::META_CONFIG_PATH,
                    $meta,
                    [
                        'label' => __('Presell Product From'),
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-date',
                    ]
                );
                $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
                    $toFieldPath . self::META_CONFIG_PATH,
                    $meta,
                    [
                        'label' => __('To'),
                        'scopeLabel' => null,
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-date',
                    ]
                );
                $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
                    $fromContainerPath . self::META_CONFIG_PATH,
                    $meta,
                    [
                        'label' => false,
                        'required' => false,
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__control-grouped-date',
                        'breakLine' => false,
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
                    ]
                );
                $meta = $this->arrayManager->set(
                    $fromContainerPath . '/children/' . self::PRESALE_END,
                    $meta,
                    $this->arrayManager->get($toFieldPath, $meta)
                );

                return $this->arrayManager->remove($toContainerPath, $meta);
            }
   ```

   }

Comment: I think you need to pass config to JS component, like: imports: {visible: "${ $.provider }:is_presale_product"} . Exact syntax to be clarified :)

Comment: Please, who can help me?

Comment: Is it still relevant?

Comment: @Roman Kabanov Yes, it's still relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Modify source model so that "No" has empty value instead of '0':

   ```php
   <?php

   namespace Ns\MyModule\Model\Config\Source;

   class PresaleSchedule extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
   {

       protected $_optionsData;

       public function getAllOptions()
       {
           if ($this->_options === null) {
               $this->_options = [
                   ['value' => '', 'label' => __('No')],
                   ['value' => 1, 'label' => __('Yes')]
               ];
           }
           return $this->_options;
       }
   }
   ```

   This is because Magento automatically converts options to string in \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\AbstractOptionsField::prepare. And for JavaScript option '0' is "truthy" and not recognized as `visible: false`.
2. Add imports > visible on components that should depend on another field:

   ```
   'imports' => [
       'visible' => 'product_form.product_form_data_source:data.product.is_presale_product',
   ]
   ```

   Full method:

   ```php
   protected function customizeDateRangeField(array $meta)
   {
       if ($this->getGroupCodeByField($meta, self::PRESALE_START)
           !== $this->getGroupCodeByField($meta, self::PRESALE_END)
       ) {
           return $meta;
       }

       $fromFieldPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath(self::PRESALE_START, $meta, null, 'children');
       $toFieldPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath(self::PRESALE_END, $meta, null, 'children');
       $fromContainerPath = $this->arrayManager->slicePath($fromFieldPath, 0, -2);
       $toContainerPath = $this->arrayManager->slicePath($toFieldPath, 0, -2);

       $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
           $fromFieldPath . self::META_CONFIG_PATH,
           $meta,
           [
               'label' => __('Presell Product From'),
               'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-date',
           ]
       );
       $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
           $toFieldPath . self::META_CONFIG_PATH,
           $meta,
           [
               'label' => __('To'),
               'scopeLabel' => null,
               'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-date',
           ]
       );
       $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
           $fromContainerPath . self::META_CONFIG_PATH,
           $meta,
           [
               'label' => false,
               'required' => false,
               'additionalClasses' => 'admin__control-grouped-date',
               'breakLine' => false,
               'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
               'imports' => [
                   'visible' => 'product_form.product_form_data_source:data.product.is_presale_product',
               ]
           ]
       );
       $meta = $this->arrayManager->set(
           $fromContainerPath . '/children/' . self::PRESALE_END,
           $meta,
           $this->arrayManager->get($toFieldPath, $meta)
       );

       return $this->arrayManager->remove($toContainerPath, $meta);
   }
   ```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It works!

Comment: @МатвейБойко I'm glad :) Should the answer be marked as accepted, or more clarification is needed?

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing this in a UI Component Form You can Follow These Steps to Achieve Your Goal

1. Create A Custom Select Component for the Yes/No Field by extending the Select Component

   ```
   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Custom_Module/js/element/yesNo</item>
   ```
2. Override the OnChange Method of Select Component
3. Get The To and From Fields from UiRegistry using their id
4. Check the Current Selected Option of yes/No Field
5. if the value is No run .hide() function for both To and Form Fields

I will add Code to each step if I have got time

Thank You